# App Engine Node.js Error: Too many messages queued

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, nodemailer

I have a form in my website that allows visitors to drop me a mail directly. The server is built on express.js and the email is sent through nodemailer and nodemailer-mailgun-transport.

It successfully sends emails to my account on my local PC but my `server.js` returns `Error: Too many messages queued` when I tried to host the website on GCP App Engine. I guess it might just an error caused by the queue configuration, but I couldn't find where to fix it.

Browser log:
[image]

Here's the code:
`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sendMail = require('./mail.js')
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const log = console.log;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//data parsing
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/email', (req, res) => {
    // send email here
    const { name, email, subject, text } = req.body;
    log('Data : ', req.body);

    sendMail(name, email, subject, text, function(err, data)  {
        if(err)  {
            log('\n'+err+'\ndata: '+data);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Error' });
        }
        else  {
            log('Email sent!!!');
            res.json({ message: 'Email sent!!!' });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    log('Server is listening on port ', 8080);
});
```

`mail.js`

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailGun = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');

const auth = {
    auth: {
        api_key: [API_KEY],
        domain: [DOMAIN]
    }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailGun(auth));

const sendMail = (name, email, subject, text, cb) =>  {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: email,
        to: [MY_EMAIL],
        subject,
        text: name + ' ' + text
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, data)  {
        if(err)  {
            // console.log('Error occurs');
            cb(err, null);
        }
        else  {
            // console.log('Message sent!!!');
            cb(null, data);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = sendMail;
```

`script` in `index.html`

```
<script>
        $('form').on('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const name = $('#name').val().trim();
            const email = $('#email').val().trim();
            const subject = $('#subject').val().trim();
            const text = $('#text').val().trim();

            if (name == '' || email=='' || subject=='' || text=='') {
                alert('Message not sent!!! Please fill out the form properly.');
            }
            else {
                const data = {
                    name,
                    email,
                    subject,
                    text
                }

                $.post('/email', data, function () {
                    console.log('Server received our data');
                });

                $('#name').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#subject').val('');
                $('#text').val('');

                alert('Message sent!');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `[MY_EMAIL]`? Is it possible that this is empty? Also, why is there a `subject` without any value attributed to it on your `mailOptions`? If you remove this, does the error also occurs?

Comment: @ralemos I censored my actual gmail with MY_EMAIL. The `subject` is a short term of `subject: subject`, which is the subject to be sent to my email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your Mailgun key via the `app.yaml` file.

```
runtime: nodejs
env_variables:
  MAILGUN_API_KEY: your-mailgun-api-key
```

Here's a full tutorial https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/send-email-with-mailgun-and-nodejs-on-google-app-engine